# Early stopping based on BLEU in FairSeq

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, machine-translation, bleu, fairseq

My goal is to use BLEU as early stopping metric while training a translation model in FairSeq.

Following the documentation, I am adding the following arguments to my training script:

```
--eval-bleu --eval-bleu-args --eval-bleu-detok --eval-bleu-remove-bpe
```

I am getting the following error:

```
fairseq-train: error: unrecognized arguments: --eval-bleu --eval-bleu-args --eval-bleu-detok --eval-bleu-remove-bpe
```

System information:

- fairseq version: 0.10.2
- torch: 1.10.1+cu113

More Details:

When I am trying to finetune M2M100 model, I am getting error as:

KeyError: 'bleu'

when using following:

```bash
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 fairseq-train \
    $path_2_data --ddp-backend=no_c10d \
    --best-checkpoint-metric bleu \
    --maximize-best-checkpoint-metric \
    --max-tokens 2048 --no-epoch-checkpoints \
    --finetune-from-model $pretrained_model \
    --save-dir $checkpoint --task translation_multi_simple_epoch \
    --encoder-normalize-before \
    --langs 'af,am,ar,ast,az,ba,be,bg,bn,br,bs,ca,ceb,cs,cy,da,de,el,en,es,et,fa,ff,fi,fr,fy,ga,gd,gl,gu,ha,he,hi,hr,ht,hu,hy,id,ig,ilo,is,it,ja,jv,ka,kk,km,kn,ko,lb,lg,ln,lo,lt,lv,mg,mk,ml,mn,mr,ms,my,ne,nl,no,ns,oc,or,pa,pl,ps,pt,ro,ru,sd,si,sk,sl,so,sq,sr,ss,su,sv,sw,ta,th,tl,tn,tr,uk,ur,uz,vi,wo,xh,yi,yo,zh,zu' \
    --lang-pairs $lang_pairs \
    --decoder-normalize-before --sampling-method temperature \
    --sampling-temperature 1.5 --encoder-langtok src \
    --decoder-langtok --criterion label_smoothed_cross_entropy \
    --label-smoothing 0.2 --optimizer adam --adam-eps 1e-06
    --adam-betas '(0.9, 0.98)' --lr-scheduler inverse_sqrt \
    --lr 3e-05 --warmup-updates 2500 --max-update 400000 \
    --dropout 0.3 --attention-dropout 0.1 \
    --weight-decay 0.0 --update-freq 2 --save-interval 1 \
    --save-interval-updates 5000 --keep-interval-updates 10 \
    --seed 222 --log-format simple --log-interval 2 --patience 5  \
    --arch transformer_wmt_en_de_big --encoder-layers 24 \
    --decoder-layers 24 --encoder-ffn-embed-dim 8192 \
    --decoder-ffn-embed-dim 8192 --encoder-layerdrop 0.05 \
    --decoder-layerdrop 0.05 --share-decoder-input-output-embed \
    --share-all-embeddings --fixed-dictionary $fix_dict --fp16 \
    --skip-invalid-size-inputs-valid-test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task that you are using [`translation_multi_simple_epoch`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/main/fairseq/tasks/translation_multi_simple_epoch.py) does not have these arguments; they are specific for `translation` task.

Note that some of the arguments that you are using require values.

- `--eval-bleu-args` expects a path to a configuration JSON for SacreBLEU.  If you want to you the default 4-gram BLEU, you should skip this.
- `--eval-bleu-detok` expects a specification of how you want to detokenize the model output. The default value is `space` which does not do anything.

For more details, see the [documentation of the translation task](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.2/tasks.html#translation) in FairSeq.

Comment: There might be cases where you must use translation_multi_simple_epoch as the task, instead of "translation". In this case, you can't do early stopping based on bleu?